# There is already an object named 'STUDENTS' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a database `MYDB11AM` and a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS 
(
     STID INT, 
     SNAME CHAR(10), 
     SFEE DECIMAL(6,2), 
     AGE TINYINT
)
```

but I am getting an error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
>   There is already an object named 'STUDENTS' in the database

The thing is previously I created and dropped the same `STUDENTS` table. Please help me

Comment: It seems that the table is not dropped after all, but try write `select * from students` and see what happens.

Comment: I gave the select *from students that show as : Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'STUDENTS' in the database.

Comment: That seems odd. Be sure to disconnect/close everything connected to that server, and connect again. Then try `select * from students` again. Are you using Sql Management Studio?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that some other object (maybe a view or a stored procedure) with name `STUDENTS` exists in your database?

You can check this by `sp_help` procedure. You need to have at least one of the permission on the object:

```
USE [MYDB11AM] 
GO
EXEC sp_help '[STUDENTS]'
```

If there is no error returned, there is an object named `STUDENTS` in your database for sure.

Take a look at the `Type` column of first resultset, it will let you know what type of object is (like a stored procedure or a view). You can read more about `sp_help` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).